# Parent Container Doesn't Respect Child Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty common question, and typically revolves around a current situation, so after reading up on a bunch of different solutions and trying to slide them in I thought I'd just ask the age old question myself based on my situation.

**Situation**

I've built a little page slider using jQuery, and it appears to work as expected, then I noticed the CSS height was still set to a default value I had used for testing.  After removing it I can't seem to get the height of the parent to open to the height of the different children.  I know that setting the position of the different divs to relative instead of absolute will display them, but then the divs aren't positioned correctly anymore (situated underneath each other).  Other solutions I've found revolve around not using markup that is even remotely common to my own.

**Question**

Is there a CSS fix for this that allows me to leverage Bootstrap the way I have it set up, and the jQuery animation I've already written?  Or is their any suggestion(s) that will make this work without too much alteration to the markup?  I've tried a couple different variations and this seems to be the most stable.

**Code**

I've added it to a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwbwaya5/7/).  I couldn't get the animation to work in the fiddle for some reason (works on my laptop in all browsers), but the default layout should be enough to see how the parent doesn't respect the child elements.

```
<style>
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.windowBox {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.page1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999; /* set to be over page2 onload */
}
.page2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99; /* set to be under page1 onload */
}
</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Header text should be above either page.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" id="showPage1" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Page 1</button>
            <button type="button" id="showPage2" class="btn btn-primary">Page 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 windowBox">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box page1">
                    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6">...</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="box page2">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Footer text should be under either page.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u state ur exact question in single sentence?

Comment: hey @Victor, I sure can.  Can this Bootstrap markup be made to respect the heights of the currently displayed content using CSS?

Comment: HERE IS YOUR FIDDLE WORKING: https://jsfiddle.net/poi33/zwbwaya5/9/
sorry for the all caps... used some time to fix it. Now what you want is the content that scrolls / fades to be scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/poi33/zwbwaya5/10/)

Added an .over class to your markup. 
Thats the only change made there.

**css**
Over class is the container of the windowBox.
We want this to have a hidden overflow because it will contain all our pages side by side.

```
.over {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is a fixed value unfortunately. Basically its the width of your window X pages. If your going to add more then just one page, you can set this value in JavaScript.

```
.windowBox {
    width: 220vw;
}
```

Then we simply set the container to be a "kind of" fixed width.
responsive width.. so 95 of view port width is reasonable.

```
.box {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 95vw;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

And in the JavaScript instead of setting the `left` property you set the `margin-left`.
You only need to do this for the first element so. If you want to scroll to page 4 you can set the first pages margin to `-4 * 95vw`